# Nginx cache ignore get variables

Tags: php, caching, nginx

I have some GET variables which are used by JS elements only.

My application was fast with nginx caching but now with the get variables, there's no caching. There could be 20 to 30 different variations on a URL.

Is it possible to configure nginx so it ignores everything after the `?` in the URL in regards to caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just update the cachekey like:

```
$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$geoip_country_code? my_get_var1=$arg_my_get_var1&my_get_var2=$arg_my_get_var2
```